# Why single quotes are escaped by grails' google visualisation plugin?

Tags: javascript, grails, google-visualization

I'm using Google visualisation plugin in a grails app. I'm trying to paint a line chart which fails because the single quotes around string data for the x axis are escaped.

In my gsp page I put:

```
<gvisualization:apiImport/>
<%
    def columns = [['string', 'Date'], ['number', 'Value']]
    def chartData = [['20.02.2014', 123], ['21.02.2014', 456]]
%>
<gvisualization:lineCoreChart
    elementId="chartView" columns="${columns}" data="${chartData}" width="250" height="200"/>
```

which is translated into this (source code of the page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

    function drawVisualization() {
        visualization_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        visualization_data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        visualization_data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
        visualization_data.addRow([&#39;20.02.2014&#39;, 123]);      
        visualization_data.addRow([&#39;21.02.2014&#39;, 456]);

        visualization = new  oogle.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartView'));

        visualization.draw(visualization_data, {width: &#39;250&#39;, height: &#39;200&#39;});   
    }
 </script>
```

I'm using grails 2.3.5 and Google visualisation plugin 0.6.2. I have no idea why the single quotes are escaped in the generated JS code. Any hint is appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:**

I debugged into the plugin. The first value in the array is correctly recognized as a string. Then the value gets wrapped into single quotes. So I guess the error is introduced when the generated Javascript is written to the page. So it's maybe a bug in the plugin...?

Answer (score 1):

A few months late, but for anyone else experiencing this issue, it turns out it's the default config file with Grails 2.3.5 and up.

Solution is found here:  [Grails 2.3.5 default Config.groovy causes render issues for Google Visualization tags](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPGOOGLEVISUALIZATIONAPI-14)

The problematic line is `scriptlet = 'html'`. The [security docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/security.html) describe how to add a per-plugin encoding or a per-page encoding.

This is the per-plugin encoding. Just add this to your Config.groovy, and it'll work on all pages.

```
googleVisualization.grails.views.gsp.codecs.scriptlet = "none"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding ';' to the end of your definitions??

Like so:

```
def columns = [['string', 'Date'], ['number', 'Value']];
def chartData = [['20.02.2014', 123], ['21.02.2014', 456]];
```

Shouldn't have to but it's just a thought.

I literally have no clue but what i would try is:

Escaping the quotes yourself - `def chartData = [[\'20.02.2014\', 123], ['21.02.2014', 456]];`

And maybe wrap your single quotes in doubles.. "'"20.02.2014"'"?

Sorry i wasn't much help but worth a shot.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using double quotes instead of single quotes?

I'm not familiar with that plugin, but it may use some java-based libraries like many plugins, with a thin groovyfication layer.

It looks like a bug in the translation to javascript. If the translator is originally java-centric, they might have forgotten about considering that single quotes delimit a string in groovy.